# didActivateNotification is not responding to NSUserNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

I'm working to get osx native notifications working. I'm able to create a notification but not get the didActivateNotification working. I want didActivateNotification to allow me to focus the window and remove the notification from the notification center.

Here is my code: `notice.m`

```
#import "Notice.h"

@implementation Notice

- (void) notify:(NSDictionary *)message {

    NSLog(@"Notification - Show it");

    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    [notification setTitle:[message valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [notification setInformativeText:[message valueForKey:@"content"]];
    [notification setDeliveryDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [notification setSoundName:NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName];
    NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    [center scheduleNotification:notification];
}

- (void) userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didActivateNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
{

    NSLog(@"Notification - Clicked");

    notification=nil;
    [center removeDeliveredNotification: notification];
}
```

This is firing properly:

```
NSLog(@"Notification - Show it");
```

But this is not:

```
NSLog(@"Notification - Clicked");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have to set the delegate for `NSUserNotificationCenter`:

```
NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
```

You should also make sure your `Notice` class implements the `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, where would that go exactly?

Comment: That errors with "Properly delegate not found on object of type NSUserNotification *"

Comment: Nice that worked. it then caused an error in the other func, but that's prob a separate question. Thank you "2012-11-02 17:28:05.133 MacGap[17588:303] *** -[_NSConcreteUserNotificationCenter removeDeliveredNotification:] requires a NSUserNotification object. Passed with NULL.
"

Comment: That is because you need to swap the bottom two lines in your `userNotificationCenter: didActivateNotification` method.